# Using tapestry-jpa just with tapestry-ioc in non-web project

Tags: jpa, tapestry

this is a very basic question, and I'm kind of sorry, but I don't seem to be able to get a simple Tapestry-IOC based application to work with the built-in Tapestry JPA module.

The application is not necessarily meant as a web project so the dependencies are just tapestry-ioc and tapestry-jpa for the JPA integration. I used the hibernate-entitymanager before and everything worked fine. But I thought I might rather use the official JPA support of Tapestry.

So what I did was to get the above mentioned dependencies (in Tapestry version 5.3.7) and to write the beginning of a test.
This beginning looks like this

```
Registry registry = RegistryBuilder.buildAndStartupRegistry(MyModule.class);
EntityManager em = registry.getService(EntityManager.class);
```

That's all. Because as soon as I try this I get the error that no service would implement the `EntityManager` interface.

So I added the Tapestry JPA module:

```
Registry registry = RegistryBuilder.buildAndStartupRegistry(MyModule.class, JpaModule.class);
```

But then again I get an error that the `JpaModule` wants to contribute to the `ApplicationStatePersistenceStrategySource` service which is not present. This service seems to be defined in the `TapestryModule` so I did

```
Registry registry = RegistryBuilder.buildAndStartupRegistry(MyModule.class, JpaModule.class, TapestryModule.class);
```

But this causes an error due to the missing servlet API. So now I get to the point where I would have to define the web environment for Tapestry. But I don't want this, I just wanted to use the JPA integration.

Is this even possible? And if so, how do I do it? Following the documentation at http://tapestry.apache.org/integrating-with-jpa.html does not help in this regard.

Thank you very much for reading, any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer -- I could be wrong -- but I thought Tapestry-jpa was intended for using JPA with Tapestry-core (the web framework). I don't think there would be any benefit over plain JPA in your case.

Comment: Well, as I see it, the advantages of using the official Tapestry JPA support is the transaction management, e.g. via the @CommitAfter annotation, automatic package scanning for entities, the framework-management of the EntityManager and possibly other stuff. All this I can also do when I just use Tapestry-JPA with IOC services. However, perhaps I just missed the real cool reasons to use the Tapestry-JPA integration in the first place? :-)